# Apply some css to the last child

Tags: css

I am new to the web developement. here I have css

```
.bgStatusMenuOptions li:not(:last-child) {
  font: var(--typography-body1);
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f6f6f6;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.41px;
  background-color: #ffffff; /** Need to handle in the style component as well **/
}
```

Now, In this I don't want to apply the border to the last element only other css should get applied. I have a solution which will be like ,

creating two diff places. but is there any way to do this in the same place ?

Comment: What do you mean by "diff places" and "same place"?

Comment: I mean in the same class like the same blog

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need two different style rules for that

```css
.bgStatusMenuOptions li {
   ...rules for all
} 
.bgStatusMenuOption li:last-child {
  ...rules for last child only
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in another way

```
.bgStatusMenuOptions li {
  font: var(--typography-body1);
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f6f6f6;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.41px;
  background-color: #ffffff; /** Need to handle in the style component as well **/
} 

.bgStatusMenuOptions li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add this to the css:

```
.bgStatusMenuOptions li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

This will remove the bottom border from the last child.
The others should remain the same:

```
.bgStatusMenuOptions li {
  font: var(--typography-body1);
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f6f6f6;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.41px;
  background-color: #ffffff; /** Need to handle in the style component as well **/
}
```

Comment: But other properties should also get applied

Comment: I assumed you get the idea, answer updated

Answer (score 0):

```
.bgStatusMenuOptions li:last-child {
  font: var(--typography-body1);
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f6f6f6;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.41px;
  background-color: #ffffff; /** Need to handle in the style component as well **/
}
```

if you know elements you can use `nth-last-child` as well like-

```css
p:nth-last-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
```